# Class Under Test vs Object Under Test

Tags: test-management, testng

What is the difference between Class Under Test (CUT) and Object Under Test (OUT)?

> - *CUT is used to test a class*
> - *and OUT is used to test an object.*

I'm unable to find any difference other than the above-mentioned one.

Comment: Where did you see this?

Answer (score 3):

It grow too long for a comment, so here it goes:

Class is like a recipe, objects is like food prepared according to it (instance of a class). You cannot test class, like you cannot taste recipe: only instance of that class is something you can interact with.

Of course all instances of a class should behave the same, so you can think about "testing a class" when you really test instances of that class (objects). So the source of your confusion is just a mental shortcut.

Comment: Do you mean a class and an object in object-oriented sense? If so,  then to be precise, you can test directly some parts of a class, i. e,., static methods and static fields.

Comment: @dzieciou - Correct, if you want to be very precise.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this is a generic answer; your environment may have its own interpretation that differs.

***In short a class is the code that describes what the object does.*** The object comes into existence when the class code is called and one particular object is instantiated. When it is instantiated the object sits in your computer memory ready to do its work; its  properties are filled with the particular values that belong to it. One class can be called multiple times to instantiate all the needed variations of the class.
***Example:*** Class book is called repeatedly to fill the Library object with all the book titles.

So in this case **Class Under Test** would be the test about the variations the class allows, that instantiation can succeed, that nice failures are shown for illegal instantiation attempts etc. 
***Example:*** Is this class suitable to put into Library and can it do all that we need from it there? Does it have a title property, guaranteed? Is it ensured the title cannot be changed?

**Object under test** would be that the successfully instantiated object behaves well. That the properties and methods do the work they should do. 
***Example:*** Does this library book properly show its title "War and Peace"?

It does not help that often class and object are used interchangeable. Also see [Class vs Object](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Class_vs_Object)